# Split the restaurant bill

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript and I've set up a bill calculator. Most of the lines in the code are to deal with rounding. It has four main components:

1. Allows you to enter the bill amount and tip percentage.
2. Calculates the total bill divided by the number of guests.
3. Calculates the total tip.
4. Splits the bill by the number of guests.

```
billAmount = 134.93
const enterTipPercent = 10
const guests = ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"]
const noOfGuests = guests.length;
console.log('Chosen tip: ' + enterTipPercent + '%')

function splitBill() {
  var split = billAmount / noOfGuests; 
  var rounding = split.toFixed(2);
  var elseIf = rounding * noOfGuests;

if (rounding == billAmount/noOfGuests) {
  console.log('Each person must pay: £' + rounding +' with no remainder');

}

else if (elseIf * noOfGuests > billAmount){
  var roundDown = Math.floor(split*100) /100;
  var remainingAmount = billAmount-roundDown*noOfGuests;
  var roundedRemainder = remainingAmount.toFixed(2);
  console.log('Each person must pay: £' + roundDown +' with £' + roundedRemainder + ' remaining');
  }
}

function calculateTip() {
  var tip = billAmount/100*enterTipPercent;
  var tipRound = tip.toFixed(2);
  return tipRound;
}

function splitTip() {

  if (calculateTip() * 10 == billAmount) {
    var tipShare = calculateTip();
    var tipDivide = tipShare/noOfGuests;
    var tipRound = tipDivide.toFixed(2);
    console.log('Each person must tip: £' + tipRound);
}
  else  {
  var tipShare = calculateTip();
  var tipDivide = tipShare/noOfGuests;
  var tipRound = Math.floor(tipDivide *100) /100;
  var tipremainder = calculateTip()-tipRound*noOfGuests;
  var tipRoundRemainder = tipremainder.toFixed(2);
  console.log('Each person must tip: £' + tipRound + ' with £' + tipRoundRemainder + ' remaining');
  }
}

splitBill();
console.log('total tip £' + calculateTip());
splitTip();const
```

The code I've written works fine, but I'm sure this isn't the best, or most efficient way I could have done it. Does anyone have any advice on how I can improve?

Answer (score 3):

Short review;

- Use a beautifier, the code is not properly indented or spaced out
- You use `var`, try to use `const` and `let`
- The code already assigned `billAmount / noOfGuests` to `split`, so you can compare `rounding` and `split`
- £ should probably be a single string constant
- `elseIf` is a terrible variable name
- `elseIf` is already multiplied by `noOfGuests`, why would you multiply it again in the `if` statement?
- `billAmount` and `noOfGuests` should be parameters of `splitBill` and `splitTip`
- `tipremainder` should be `tipRemainder`

Comment: Emphasis on: Stop Using Var.